# nodejs split image into chunks

Tags: node.js, image, split

Is there a nodeJS-way to split an image into single chunks?
Probably with different dimensions?

Like the photos on image below

[image: This is an example wat i will do]

Answer (score 4):

I've done something like this using [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp), however it can probably be much more concise...

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

/**
 * @param filename - input file
 * @param numSlices - how many slices
 * @param attenuation - how quickly slices get smaller
 */
function sliceImage(filename, numSlices, attenuation) {
    Jimp.read(filename).then(image => {
        let w = image.bitmap.width;
        let h = image.bitmap.height;
        let sliceWidth = w / numSlices;
        let midlane = w / 2;
        let slack = 0.001;

        let slices = [];

        function slicePair(left, right) {
            if (left < (0 - slack) || (right - sliceWidth) > (w + slack)) {
                return;
            }

            let leftSlice = image.clone();
            let rightSlice = image.clone();

            leftSlice.crop(left, 0, sliceWidth, h);
            rightSlice.crop(right - sliceWidth, 0, sliceWidth, h);

            slices.push(leftSlice);
            slices.push(rightSlice);

            slicePair(left - sliceWidth, right + sliceWidth);
        }

        function doSlice() {
            if (numSlices % 2 == 0) {
                slicePair(midlane - sliceWidth, midlane + sliceWidth);
            } else {
                let middle = image.clone();
                middle.crop(midlane - (sliceWidth / 2), 0, sliceWidth, h);
                slices.push(middle);
                slicePair(midlane - (1.5 * sliceWidth), midlane + (1.5 * sliceWidth));
            }
        }

        function overlay() {
            let canvas = image.clone().brightness(1);
            let odd = !(slices.length % 2 === 0);
            let adjust = odd ? (sliceWidth / 2) : 0;
            slices.reverse();
            if (odd) {
                let middle = slices.pop();
                canvas.composite(middle, (midlane - (sliceWidth / 2)), 0);
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < (slices.length + 2); i++) {
                let k = odd ? (i + 1) : i;
                let left = slices.pop().crop(0, attenuation * k, sliceWidth, (h - (attenuation * k) * 2));
                let right = slices.pop().crop(0, attenuation * k, sliceWidth, (h - (attenuation * k) * 2));
                canvas.composite(left, (midlane - ((i + 1) * sliceWidth)) - adjust, (attenuation * k));
                canvas.composite(right, (midlane + (i * sliceWidth)) + adjust, (attenuation * k));
            }
            canvas.write("result.jpg");
            return canvas;
        }

        doSlice();
        return overlay();
    });
}
```

Comment: It's near on what i want to do, but it generates me an image with just 1 slice in the middle. I've tried to edit the script to get the result i want, but i can't find the part wehere i have to change it

Answer (score 0):

```
const Jimp = require('jimp') ;
const forloop=require('async-for-loop');
const width=1000, height=716,h=7,v=7;
async function crop(source,filename,offSetX, offSetY, width,height,cb) { 
   // Reading Image
   const image = await Jimp.read
   (source);
   image.crop(offSetX, offSetY, width,height)
   .write(filename);

}
//
forloop(h,(hi,nextH)=>{
  forloop(v,async (vi,nextV)=>{
    await crop('/Users/you/Projects/sliceit/imgs/image.jpg',`/Users/you/Projects/sliceit/out/slice_${hi}_${vi}.jpg`,
      hi*width,vi*height,width,height,nextV
    );
    nextV();
  },()=>{
    nextH();
  })
},()=>{
  console.log("Image is processed successfully");
})
```